# Using logic AND in a text field

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using a schema that has a text field containing ids separated by spaces. The field definition in schema is below:

`<field name="aux_identifiers" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

a query that fetch a single document returns the field as below - example:

```
<str name="aux_identifiers">1 2 3 4</str>
```

is there any possibility to apply a logic AND operator to these fields? I need to find the documents that has, as example, the ids 2 and 3 in the field.

fyi, **we can't modifiy those fields to multivalued or array and reindex**  right now. that's why i'm trying a alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on what kind of processing you have on that field, but this should work:

```
 q=aux_identifier:2  AND aux_identifier:3
```

Comment: i'll try this and reply the result. can this query results in performance losses?

Comment: sure, this will be slower than using fq, but I think this is the best you can do unless you change your schema.